# how to display the number 1 as 01 and how to increment that

Tags: javascript, php, html

actually i have text file like below,
.
.
.
.(file.txt)

```
;
; Message Information file
;
[message]
origmailbox=103
context=macro-vm
macrocontext=from-internal
exten=s-BUSY
rdnis=unknown
priority=3
callerchan=SIP/103-0000001a
callerid="103" <103>
origdate=Fri May  2 04:51:01 PM UTC 2014
origtime=1399049461
category=
flag=
duration=2
```

I need to display these contents in webpage. so I'm used

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents(path,NULL,NULL,start,end);
echo $data;
?>
```

but the last line in the text file "duration=2" is not better.
I want to display duration in seconds like "duration=0.02".
but I don't make changes in the text file.

how to display that on webpage?

and if the text file has "duration=10",
I want to automatically change the "duration=0.02" to "duration=0.10" in webpage

please help me

Comment: Use `printf` or `sprintf` to format numbers output

Comment: Why is this labelled "mysql"?

Comment: you can also use [`str_pad()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Comment: `preg_replace( "/duration=(\d+)/e", "sprintf('duration=0.%02d', $1)", $data );`

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because this seems to have nothing to do with databases or MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

little bit long but works

```
$values = file('filename.ext');

$search="duration";$data='';

foreach (array_values($values) AS $line)
{

list($key, $val) = explode('=', trim($line) );

if (trim($key) == $search)
    {
    $data .= $key.'='.($val/100);
}
else
{
$data .= $line;
}
}
```